# Is $\Bbb K^2$ a simple extension of $\Bbb K$?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

$\textbf {Definition} :$ Let $\Bbb K$ be a base field. Let $A$ be a $\Bbb K$-algebra. Then $A$ is said to be a simple extension of $\Bbb K$ if $\exists$ $x \in A$ such that $A=\Bbb K[x]$ as $\Bbb K$-algebras. In this case we say that $x$ is a primitive element of $A$ over $\Bbb K.$

$\textbf {Question} :$ Is $\Bbb K^2$ a simple extension of $\Bbb K$?

To get an answer of the above question we need only to ensure whether or not there exists an element $x = (a,b) \in \Bbb K^2$ such that $\Bbb K^2 = \Bbb K[(a,b)]$ as $\Bbb K$-algebras. Am I correct? I know that since $\Bbb K$ is a field I can always find two elements $a,b \in \Bbb K$ with $a \neq b.$ Will this two distinct elements in $\Bbb K$ work?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

**EDIT** $:$ I observe that for any $F \in \Bbb K[X]$ we have $F((a,b)) = (F(a),F(b)).$ So we need only to find out two polynomials $F,G \in \Bbb K[X]$ such that $F(a)=1,F(b)=0$ and $G(a)=0,G(b)=1.$ Since $\Bbb K^2 = \text {span}\ \{(1,0),(0,1) \}.$ Let $a=1,b=0$ and let us take $F(X) = X$ and $G(X) = (X-1)^2.$ Then we are through.

Comment: Yes, that'll work. A particularly easy choice is $x = (1, 0)$, say.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan what can I say about $\Bbb K^3$ or more generally $\Bbb K^n$ for $n \geq 3.$

Comment: It's simple iff $|K| \ge n$.

Comment: Yeah I am now fully convinced with your argument @QiaochuYuan. Since $\Bbb K^n$ is a finite dimensional $\Bbb K$-algebra every element of $\Bbb K^n$ is algebraic over $\Bbb K.$ Let $a=(a_1,a_2, \cdots, a_n) \in \Bbb K^n.$ Let $\mu_a$ be the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\Bbb K.$ Then we know that $$\text {deg}\ (\mu_a) = \text {Dim}_{\Bbb K}\ (\Bbb K[a]).$$ Now $\text {deg}\ (\mu_a) =$ number of distinct components in $a.$ Since $\Bbb K[a] \subseteq \Bbb K^n$ so $$\Bbb K[a] = \Bbb K^n \Longleftrightarrow \text{Dim}_{\Bbb K}\ (\Bbb K[a]) = \text {Dim}_{\Bbb K}\ (\Bbb K^n) =n.$$

Comment: So $\Bbb K^n$ is a simple extension of $\Bbb K$ iff $\exists$ $a=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n) \in \Bbb K^n$ all of whose components are distinct or in other words $\Bbb K$ has at least $n$-distinct elements in it i.e. $|\Bbb K| \geq n.$ Am I correct @QiaochuYuan?

Comment: So from the above discussion it is quite clear that $\Bbb Z_2^3$ is not a simple extension of $\Bbb Z_2$ as $|\Bbb Z_2| = 2 \not\geq 3.$

Comment: Yes, that’s all correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98770/discussion-between-math-maniac-and-qiaochu-yuan).